# Save opened images and reopen them after reboot

Tags: command-line, scripts, session

My linux scripting skills are poor so I'm hoping someone can help.

I have 50+ images open via FEH from many different locations, I do not want to individually search for them after reboot.

```
ps aux | grep feh
```

shows many

```
[...] 0:00 feh --start-at /media/[...]/x.jpg
```

along with

```
[...] 0:00 grep --color=auto feh
```

I need a script that would allow me to save them into a file and then be able to restore them from file somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract the list of start commands and save the output in a file:

```bsh
ps aux|grep -oP "[f]eh.*" >~/feh_commands
```

Make it a proper script by adding a shebang, quoting the file names and adding `&` to each line to run them simultaneously:

```bsh
sed -i 's_/_"/_;s/$/" \&/;1i#!/bin/bash' ~/feh_commands
```

Now you just need to run the script with

```bsh
bash ~/feh_commands
```

or make it executable and run it.